# PyQt load images in background process

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, pyqt

I am building an application that needs to load 100-200 images (really only limited by performance) and display them to the user in a sort of gallery. A good analogy would simply be Google Images. In a linear implementation loading 100 images takes roughly 3-6 seconds, during which the GUI is frozen. I tried offloading this to a background thread, but quickly learned that QPixmap is not thread-safe and can only be created in the GUI thread. So naturally I looked into multiprocessing and discovered that this is a much more difficult problem than I thought due to the GIL when it comes to threading, and lack of shared-state when it comes to multiprocessing...

So I was able to write a sample application that can load up a bunch of QLabels and populate them in the background using a series of threads, locks, queues, and processes which I have cobbled together into an `ImageManger` class. This involves creating the widgets in the main GUI thread, loading `QImage's` in a background process, pickling them, re-constructing a `QImage` in a background thread, and then finally using a signal to emit this new `QImage` from the background thread into the GUI thread where it is converted into a `QPixmap`.

Overall I am actually quite surprised at how well this is working out! However I am posting up on Code Review because I want to test my knowledge of threading, multiprocessing and concurrency in PyQt which is still somewhat rough ground for me. My questions are: have I done this in the best way? Is this overly complex and there is a much better solution? Can this be optimized further?

My requirements are that the GUI thread is blocked as little as possible, and there are placeholders for the images that get populated as they buffer. Speed is a concern, but I am more concerned about keeping the GUI fluid and if this adds a bit of time to the overall process I can live with that (and so can the users!).

Here's my working code. Sorry for the large amount of lines, I have tried to slim it down as much as possible and broke things into classes/methods to keep them (hopefully) descriptive:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
from queue import Empty as QueueEmpty

PROCESS_TIMEOUT = 10

class App(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.img_loader = ImageManager(self)
        self.img_loader.image_loaded.connect(self.on_image_loaded)
        self.img_loader.start()
        
        self.img_widgets = {}
        
        # gui
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        
        img_scroll_parent = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(img_scroll_parent)
        self.img_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        img_scroll_parent.setLayout(self.img_layout)
        
        go_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('go')
        go_btn.clicked.connect(self.start_loading_images)
        self.layout.addWidget(go_btn)
        
    def start_loading_images(self):
        load_dir = r'' # <---- path to directory with TONS of images!
        for fn in os.listdir(load_dir):
            path = os.path.join(load_dir, fn)
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                if os.path.splitext(fn)[1] in ['.png', '.jpg']:
                    widget = QtWidgets.QLabel('...loading...')
                    widget.setScaledContents(True)
                    widget.setFixedHeight(100)
                    self.img_layout.addWidget(widget)
                    
                    self.img_widgets[fn] = widget
                    self.img_loader.load_image(path)
    
    def on_image_loaded(self, path, qimage):
        fn = os.path.split(path)[1]
        if fn in self.img_widgets:
            widget = self.img_widgets[fn]
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)
            if pixmap.isNull():
                print(f'Error loading {fn}')
                return
            
            h = pixmap.height()
            w = pixmap.width()
            widget.setText('')
            widget.setFixedWidth(int((widget.height() * w) / h)) # this was the fastest way I could find to set an image on a label and maintain aspect ratio.
            widget.setPixmap(pixmap)
            
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.img_loader.shutdown()
        super().closeEvent(event)
    
class ImageManager(QtCore.QObject):
    image_loaded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, QtGui.QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.work_queue = Queue()
        self.done_queue = Queue()
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.img_list = self.manager.list()
        
        self.signal_thread = self.SignalEmitter(self, self.done_queue, self.img_list)
        self.signal_thread.imgLoaded.connect(self._emit_image)
        
        self.proc_count = 4
        self.bg_procs = []
        for _ in range(self.proc_count):
            bg_proc = Process(target=self._worker, args=(self.work_queue, self.done_queue, self.img_list,))
            self.bg_procs.append(bg_proc)
            
    def start(self):
        self.signal_thread.start()
        for p in self.bg_procs:
            p.start()
        
    def shutdown(self):
        # empty queues and insert poison pills
        while not self.work_queue.empty():
            self.work_queue.get()
        for _ in range(self.proc_count):
            self.work_queue.put(None)
        
        while not self.done_queue.empty():
            self.done_queue.get()
        self.done_queue.put(None)
        
        # ensure everything shuts down
        self.signal_thread.wait()
        for p in self.bg_procs:
            p.join()
        print('Image manager shutting down')
        
    def _emit_image(self, path, qimage):
        self.image_loaded.emit(path, qimage)
    
    def load_image(self, path):
        self.work_queue.put(path)
        print(f'Added {os.path.split(path)[1]} to queue.')
        
        dead_procs = []
        for p in self.bg_procs:
            if not p.is_alive():
                dead_procs.append(p)
        
        for p in dead_procs:
            self.bg_procs.remove(p)
            
        for _ in range(len(dead_procs)):
            bg_proc = Process(target=self._worker, args=(self.work_queue, self.done_queue, self.img_list,))
            self.bg_procs.append(bg_proc)
            bg_proc.start()
        
    class SignalEmitter(QtCore.QThread):
        imgLoaded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, QtGui.QImage)
        
        def __init__(self, parent, done_queue, img_list):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.done_queue = done_queue
            self.img_list = img_list
            
        def run(self):
            while True:
                try:
                    img_path = self.done_queue.get(timeout=PROCESS_TIMEOUT)
                except QueueEmpty:
                    print("Queue empty, shutting down.")
                    return
                    
                if img_path == None:
                    break
                    
                while len(self.img_list) > 0:
                    img_data = self.img_list[0]
                    image = bytearray_to_qimage(img_data['bytes'])
                    self.imgLoaded.emit(img_data['path'], image)
                    self.img_list.pop(0)
                    
            print('Signal emitter shutting down.')
            
    @staticmethod
    def _worker(work_queue, done_queue, list):
        while True:
            path = work_queue.get()
            if path == None:
                break
            
            qimg = QtGui.QImage(path)
            img_dict = {
                'bytes': qimage_to_bytearray(qimg),
                'path': path
            }
            
            list.append(img_dict)
            done_queue.put(path)
            
        print("BG Proc shutting down.")
        return
        
def qimage_to_bytearray(qimage):
    byte_array = QtCore.QByteArray()
    stream = QtCore.QDataStream(byte_array, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    stream << qimage
    return byte_array

def bytearray_to_qimage(byte_array):
    img = QtGui.QImage()
    stream = QtCore.QDataStream(byte_array, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
    stream >> img
    return img
```

Comment: I am using 3 instances of the ImageManager in an app and realized that I am spawning like 15 subprocesses, which seems excessive. So I added a timeout to the processes similar to how the QThreadPool works so that processes eventually die and re-start as necessary. I think my implementation of the 're-start' part is a little wonky, happy for improvement there...

Comment: May i know purpose of bytearray conversion?

Comment: @NAGARAJS That makes it pickleable so that I can load it in a separate process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i run your code with UnSplash Image which is about 1.5Mb in size i got  ```qt.gui.icc: fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity``` i got this error. Do you Have any idea regarding this.

Comment: @NAGARAJS see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463848/pyqt5-fromiccprofile-failed-minimal-tag-size-sanity-error. The image still loads though right?

Comment: Yes Image loads . and I tried that solution , seems not helpful for me.

Comment: @NAGARAJS Then what's the problem? It's just a warning, you can ignore it.